# Remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list, Cracking the coding interview

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm reading through the book `Cracking the coding interview by Gayle Mcdowell` and came across an alternative solution for one of the problems on section 2 Linked lists. Specifically the problem #2.1

> Remove dups: Write code to remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list. How would you solve this problem if a temporary buffer is not allowed.

```
Example input  = [1,2,2,6,4,4,2] 

Example output = [1,2,6,4]
```

The answer the author gives in the books is the following:
Basically, it keeps to "pointers", one interates through the linked list and the other check all subsequent nodes for duplicates:

```
    public void deleteDups(Node head) {
    Node current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        Node runner = current;
        while (runner.next != null) {
            if (runner.next.data == current.data) {
                runner.next = runner.next.next;
            } else {
                runner = runner.next;
            }
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
}
```

I used recursion, and my code looks a little bit different, although (I believe) does the same thing:

```
public void removeRepetites(Node head) {
    if (head == null) return;
    int dataToRemove = head.data;
    while (head.next != null) {
        if (head.next.data == dataToRemove) {
            head.next = head.next.next;
        } else {
            removeRepetites(head.next);
            head = head.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you spot any disadvantages on my way of solving the problem?, perhaps a higher O space / time complexity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would your code cope with a list of 1,000,000 unique items?

Assuming no compiler or runtime optimisation your code would stackoverflow.

This is why tail recursion is better optimised into a loop. If you did that then, I think, it would look like the answer in the book.

Comment: Thanks! As a matter of fact, I'm performing a benchmark in my code as we speak. Will let you know how it goes

Comment: You were right, mine is more resource intensive, and takes a considerable amount of time to do accomplish the same task. In fact, it takes about 5 seconds to run a linked list with 50 nodes. While the author´s answer takes only 2ms

Answer (score 1):

In terms of complexity, it appears to me as though both implementations will result in a O(n^2) complexity, as the iterative answer involves a nested loop, and yours involves a function being called recursively n times inside of a loop executing n times.

The only issue/disadvantage i find with yours is that due to it being recursive, it will fill the stack space faster due to the recursive calls to the function. Each time the function is called, it will create a pointer to the function in the stack along with the dataToRemove variable.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is unsorted both solutions won't work, they only compare adjacent values. The only solution that I can think of would be very inefficient perfomance wise O(N^2). Iterate through the list and remove each node and after that check if the list contains nodes that are equal to removed note and remove them, then re-insert removed node.

Comment: You are correct the OPs won't work, but the book one does have two loops and will work for unsorted. See how it looks ahead through the rest of the list removing duplicates.

Comment: I guess it is technically correct to say "both won't work"! Or at least it is ambiguous enough to potentially mean "at least one will not work"

Comment: Both work, in my code I store ```int dataToRemove = head.data;``` and remove all nodes with data. I tested thoroughly before posting this question